# Two-Dimensional Arrays multiplication in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I can use zip and map method to multiply one-dimensional array.

I want to multiply two-Dimensional Arrays.

I have no idea. If I have two now

```
val x = Array(Array(1, 2),Array(3, 4),Array(5, 6))
val y = Array(Array(5, 10),Array(10, 15),Array(15, 20))
```

I wish to get Array(Array(1*5, 2*10), Array(3* 10, 4 * 15)...and so on.

In addition, I would like to get sum of all internal Arrays like:
Array(1*5 + 2*10, 3*10 + 4*15 ....)

What is the ideal way to do these in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Longer (more readable?) version:

```
x.zip(y) map { case (xe, ye) =>
  xe.zip(ye).map { case (a, b) => a * b }
}
```

Oneliner:

```
x.zip(y) map (_.zipped map (_ * _))
```

The sum:

```
x.zip(y) map (_.zipped map (_ * _)) map (_.sum)
```

Comment: It's really helpful for me.
Thank you.